# How to configure Sub domain in Apache with eatj hosting?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, dns

I have a domain ( www.0signals.com ) and want to create a sub domain, say uploads.0signals.com  How do I configure `httpd.conf` and other files? Where should I create the folder `uploads`? Do I need to create any other folders to support subdomains?

I'm using the advance plan on eatj and java as the core language. My directory structure looks like this:

- bin
- config
- lib
- webapps/ROOT
- uploads/ROOT

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I updated the zone in DNS and subdomain / domain are both pointing to the same IP. I think I'm doing something wrong with configuration file or created the folder at the wrong location.

Comment: Best suited for http://serverfault.com ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a proxy server (Apache httpd) then Tomcat doesn't care what your configuration looks like: you can serve all webapps on the same hostname (or hostnames) if you want. In that case, configure httpd for multiple VirtualHosts and then map whatever URL space you want onto Tomcat.

If, however, you want to separate your webapps so that (say) one is available on `www.0signals.com` and a different one is available on `uploads.0signals.com` (but not both), then you will have to create more than one `<Host>` in Tomcat's `server.xml` like this:

```
<Host name="localhost" appbase="webapps">
  ...
</Host>
<Host name="uploads.0signals.com" appbase="uploads">
  ...
</Host>
```

I left the default "localhost" `<Host>` in there without specifically identifying it as `www.0signals.com` because it should be the default `<Host>` and get anything that doesn't match any of the other hosts defined.

The `appbase` values are relative to Tomcat's `CATALINA_BASE` which is essentially the parent directory of wherever your existing `webapps` directory was. IF you want to fully-qualify the `appbase`, you are welcome to do so.

Once you have your `ROOT` directories (or `ROOT.war` files) in the `webapps` and `uploads` directories respectively, you should be good to go. Using the same IP address for both hostnames should not be a problem unless you want to configure SSL, in which case you are likely to have difficulty with the SSL certificate only matching a single domain. There are ways to get around that, but they are off-topic for your question.

***Update*** Oh, one more thing: there's no particular reason to use Apache httpd in this case. Are you required by `eatj` to use httpd out front? The above configuration will work just fine without httpd in the middle. If you intend to proxy all traffic to Tomcat, then there's no reason to have Apache httpd installed at all.

***Update 2012-06-29*** A couple of things:

1. Your DNS is not your problem (at least not right now):

   $ host www.0signals.com
   www.0signals.com has address 69.46.75.150
   $ host uploads.0signals.com
   uploads.0signals.com has address 69.46.75.150
2. When contacting each of `www.0signals.com` and `uploads.0signals.com`, I get responses from two different servers: `www.0signals.com` responds with a `Server` header of `Apache -Coyote/1.1` (that's Tomcat) while the other responds with `Apache/2.0.63` (that's Apache httpd). If you are using Apache httpd to handle *all* requests, then you are missing some `JkMount` (if you are using mod_jk) or `ProxyPass`/`ProxyPassReverse` (if you are using mod_proxy_*) in your `VirtualHost` for `uploads.0signals.com`. Remember that neither mod_jk nor mod_proxy_* will copy your directives from one VirtualHost to another: you have to do it manually.

Comment: Thanks for detailed information and i did as you said but it says 404. I updated DNS as well. Check out the URL http://uploads.0signals.com/index.jsp

Comment: Please post your `<Host>` configurations and update us on the locations of your files.

Comment: I uploaded the content of the file in above answer.

Comment: I removed httpd file and restarted server. I emailed eatj support team that i want to create sub-domain. They told you need to upgrade your account. Is it possible to create sub-domain with my current configuration. I own Apache server and can restart it, change the server.xml file and other you know very well.

Comment: One other domain eatj team given me is php.0signals.com and its working on `Apache/2.0.63` so what the heck is going on with uploads.0signals.com

Comment: Did you intend for `uploads.0signals.com` to be served by Apache httpd? If not, then you need to make arrangements for that. Right now, httpd is serving those requests. So, either remove httpd or configure it to proxy to Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Host appBase="uploads" autoDeploy="true" name="uploads.0signals.com" unpackWARs="true" xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
        -->

      </Host>
```

Comment: You only have one `<Host>` definition: you need two.

Comment: How we can do it? Is there anything to configure it? Or only hosting provider can do that...

Comment: You just have to keep typing: `<` then `H` then `o`, etc.